# How to pass a value from bash into expect?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, expect

I've got a really simple bash script which requires expect.
I need to pass a value from bash into expect and I'm not trying to ssh into another server or anything (cause I only seem to find questions regarding logging into another server via ssh).

The idea is simply something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Please enter your password: "
read PASSWD

x=$(expect -c '
    spawn su -c 'whoami'
    expect "Password:"
    send "$PASSWD\r"
    interact
')
```

So this doesn't work. The expect shell doesn't recognize the $PASSWD variable.
How may this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to store the PASSWD in the environment and let expect pick it up there:

```
read -p "Your password: " passwd
export passwd

expect -c '... ; send "$env(passwd)\r"; ...'
```

Probably the best choice security-wise is have expect prompt for the password: then, the password will not show up on the command line nor in the environment.

```
expect -c <<'END'
    stty -echo 
    send_user "Your password: " 
    expect_user -re "(.*)\n" 
    send_user "\n" 
    set passwd $expect_out(1,string)
    stty echo 

    # your script starts here
    ...
    send "$passwd\r"
    ...
END
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a impler way to do this with the interact command, but I'm not near my Exploring Expect book

Answer (score 0):

Variables within single quotes are not expanded by the shell, that's why in this case `$PASSWD` remains the literal string `$PASSWD`.

Try changing the quotes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Please enter your password: "
read PASSWD

x=$(expect -c "
    spawn su -c 'whoami'
    expect 'Password:'
    send '$PASSWD\r'
    interact
")
```

One more note: you should be aware that this could pose a security risk, as the password will be visible in plaintext in the process list while the command is running.